# Find the number of isometries of the brick.

Tags: metric-spaces, isometry

> Consider a brick of length $3 cm$ ,breadth $=2$ cm and height $=1$ cm
>
> Find the number of isometries of the brick.

I know that isometry means distance preserving metrics.But how to find the number of metrics which preserve distances

Please help.

Comment: turn it around in appropriate ways -- this you can simulate with a real brick. Then consider reflections mapping the brick to itself (which you cannot realize with a real brick)

Comment: Look at the extremal points / vertices, this is a finite set, an isometry induces a permutation of them, and there are not so many. Insist first that such a permutation preserves distances...